# Is there a way/tool which helps to "Find References" of a method in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

Is there a way/tool which helps to "Find References" of a method in Delphi 7 like we haven in java IDE (intellij, Eclipse)

Comment: Find in Files gets the jobs done

Comment: More recent Delphi versions support this via the Refactoring support, but there's nothing built in to D7 to do so other than Search->Find in Files.

Comment: @KenWhite, I wonder which version of IntelliJ/Eclipse he is working with.

Comment: @UweRaabe: I don't know. That feature certainly didn't exist when I last used it, but it's been a long time, so things could have changed.

Comment: @KenWhite, that's what I mean: it has changed in Delphi, too. I always wonder why people expect a more recent feature in a nearly 12 year old environment.

Comment: @UweRaabe: :-) I know; it's why I mentioned the newer versions in my first comment. Delphi 2006 introduced refactoring, IIRC. I know it's there in 2007, because I still use it every day.

Comment: Hi KenWhite. In my company the old business layer was done with delphi 7. I know it's too old but It works well and do the required job. Recently, we start a new project to migrate all this layer to new java technologies. That's why I asked this question.
I miss a think, I use intellij 12, to response to your ironical question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'usage' you mean "Where in the code is my method referenced?":
Hit `<Ctrl-Shift-Enter>` with your pointer in/on the message name.

[Added]

O sorry, you said specifically Delphi 7 - that won't work.

I'm not deleting this answer because people may not know this keyboard shortcut.
I do not know in which version this was introduced (currently using XE2)

Comment: Yes, this is the "Find References" part of refactoring I referred to in my comment to the original question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Peganza Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/#PAL) has a Cross Reference Report that seems to produce the information you need.